# What is the meaning of symbols in PexSymbolicValue.GetRawPathConditionString()?

Tags: pex, s-expression

I'm using PexSymbolicValue.GetPathConditionString() to get path condition within PexMethods. I found there is a method PexSymbolicValue.GetRawPathConditionString() that get the path conditions in S-expression format but I can't find a reference of the symbols used in its output.
Sample of this output :
“(Ceq (Ceq node null) 0)\r\n(Ceq (Ceq(select next node) null)0)\r\n(Clt (Add (select elem node)(Mul (select elem(select next node)) -1)) 1)\r\n”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description of all these symbols is available in ECMA-335 Standard Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)  Partitions I to VI http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf